# I am trying to allow the user input to select specified options from a list

Tags: python, list, input

I have only been learning Python for about two weeks and need a bit of help with an assignment. Below is the code I have written so far,

```
import random 
colour_list = ["red","blue","white","yellow","pink","orange","black","green","grey","purple"]
start_num = int(input("enter a starting number between 0 and 4\n"))
end_num = int(input("enter a end number between 5 and 9\n"))
print ("You chose ",random.choice(colour_list))
```

The task is as follows "Ask the user for a starting number between 0 and 4 and an end number between 5 and 9. Display the list for those colours between that start and end numbers the user input"

Can anyone suggest how I would link the user input to the list? Thanks in advance

Comment: are you looking for list slice syntax `l[x:y]`?

Comment: The guy below made the necessary changes, but yes just needed to specify the range from the list. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `random` here. You can do simple list slicing,

```
colour_list = ["red","blue","white","yellow","pink","orange","black","green","grey","purple"]
start_num = int(input("enter a starting number between 0 and 4\n"))
end_num = int(input("enter a end number between 5 and 9\n"))

print("You chose ",colour_list[start_num:end_num])
```

Comment: Not too sure why I used import.random as I literally wrote out the list. It's easy when you know how...Thanks a lot.